# How to data wrangle efficiently to automatize the excel process?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

There are so many macros that we do via excel but 
**can we automatize using R ?**.

Am not sure what it takes as am not an R expert yet. 
Functions like gather, spread or reshape wouldn't make much sense...
probably stringr and regrex might play a role but not proficient enough to try.

Basically,

1. We got to remove the ID's such as beet_root, apple from the "list" column (usually, starts with alphabet's except few known exceptions such as ot_p). Ofcourse, we could delete that row completely as well.
2. Create new column "names" and then append **corresponding** ID's 
   for e.g. orange ID for list value: 9734,75R4 and not 123/R90 which is corresponding to grapes ID

Please find the reprex (simplified excel process)

```
library(tidyverse)



> input
        list other_col1 other_col2
1  beet_root          a          u
2    123/92R          b          b
3    123/92R          c          q
4    10.1233          d          p
5      9.485          e          e
6       ot_p          f          f
7      apple          g          b
8    12X0893          z          z
9      123fg          h          8
10     038q4          i          i
11    orange          j          j
12      9734          k          9
13      75R4          l          l
14    grapes          m          m
15   123/R90          n          5
16   90X83.6          o          o


> expected_output
      list other_col1 other_col2     names
1  123/92R          b          b beet_root
2  123/92R          c          q beet_root
3  10.1233          d          p beet_root
4    9.485          e          e beet_root
5     ot_p          f          f beet_root
6  12X0893          z          z     apple
7    123fg          h          8     apple
8    038q4          i          i     apple
9     9734          k          9    orange
10    75R4          l          l    orange
11 123/R90          n          5    grapes
12 90X83.6          o          o    grapes
```

Data:

```
# Actual data 
input = data.frame("list" = c("beet_root","123/92R","123/92R","10.1233","9.485","ot_p",
                            "apple","12X0893","123fg","038q4",
                            "orange","9734","75R4",
                           "grapes", "123/R90","90X83.6"),
                "other_col1" = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","z",
                                "h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o"),
                "other_col2" = c("u","b","q","p","e","f","b","z",
                                "8","i","j","9","l","m","5","o"))
expected_output = data.frame("list" = c("123/92R","123/92R","10.1233","9.485","ot_p",
                                      "12X0893","123fg","038q4",
                                      "9734","75R4",
                                      "123/R90","90X83.6"),
                           "other_col1" = c("b","c","d","e",
                                            "f","z","h","i",
                                            "k","l",
                                            "n","o"
                                            ),
                           "other_col2" = c("b","q","p","e",
                                            "f","z","8","i",
                                            "9","l",
                                            "5","o"),
                           "names" = c("beet_root","beet_root","beet_root","beet_root","beet_root",
                                       "apple","apple","apple",
                                       "orange","orange",
                                       "grapes","grapes"))
```

Comment: Sounds like a merge?

Comment: really ? 
There is only 1 table as input and output

Comment: Problem is the input and expected output are hidden which makes it a bit hard to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We create a new column `names` which has value from `list` if it follows a particular pattern (starts with number or is `"ot_p"`) or has `NA`. We `fill` the `NA` values of `names` downwards and then use the same regex to `filter` the rows.

```
library(dplyr)

input %>%
  mutate(names = ifelse(!grepl("^[0-9]|ot_p", list), list, NA)) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(names) %>%
  filter(grepl("^[0-9]|ot_p", list))

#      list other_col1 other_col2     names
#1  123/92R          b          b beet_root
#2  123/92R          c          q beet_root
#3  10.1233          d          p beet_root
#4    9.485          e          e beet_root
#5     ot_p          f          f beet_root
#6  12X0893          z          z     apple
#7    123fg          h          8     apple
#8    038q4          i          i     apple
#9     9734          k          9    orange
#10    75R4          l          l    orange
#11 123/R90          n          5    grapes
#12 90X83.6          o          o    grapes
```

Ran `input[] <- lapply(input, as.character)` to convert `factors` to characters first.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse0
input %>% 
  mutate(names =  case_when(str_detect(list, "^([0-9]|ot_p)") ~ 
            NA_character_, TRUE ~ as.character(list) )) %>%
  fill(names) %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "^[0-9]|ot_p"))
```